# How to change fields and elements of XMLUI

Tags: dspace

I need to change the names of months wherever they appear in XMLUI for [DSpace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSpace).

Where do they come from? I want to change them in a programmatic way through the source
code, so that everyone who picks a month would see the words that I
want.

Should I search for April, August, etc... in the Java source or somewhere else?

Generally I'd like to know where all elements of the DRI body come from. I can't find the source code that generates them in code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the text displayed in XMLUI comes from **internationalization** directory at `[dspace]/webapps/xmlui/i18n/`, in `messages.xml`. However I do not see any month entries there, so it appears that month names are hard coded, such as it is.

The only way I'm aware of to change month names is by changing DSpace's language. However, there appears to be a bug with this function, where the months' language is set to the language of the JVM despite the DSpace language setting: see [DS-1418: Month names without translation](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-1418).

If translated month names are what you need, it may be easiest to vote on this issue and see if it gets resolved for DSpace 3.2.